# need help for creating Survey with ejs+Node.js

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to create survey using ejs as frontend and Node.js as backend and IBM db as database.
I try to search some plugin for that but no luck.Please let me know if anyone created before.

Comment: what did you try

Comment: i tries  surveyjs /surveyjs-nodejs but it is very complecated and i am not able to customize and connect with IBM DB .... so if you provide anyother framework which i can use

Comment: if you don't want any coding, try Google or Microsoft forms. Else you might try your luck with express js